# Correct syntax for taking screenshots with Selenium's WebDriverJs on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webpage-screenshot

What is the correct way of taking a screenshot when running a webdriver test with [Selenium's webdriverjs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs)?

I have the stand-alone selenium server started and I can see the command for taking screenshot is logged on the selenium-server, but the screenshot is not being saved.

My code is the following:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer('http://localURL:4444/wd/hub').withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'}).build();
driver.get([URL to webserver on my local machine])

driver.takeScreenshot("c:\\selenium_local_map\\out1.png");
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take screenshot returns a promise that will resolve with a Base64 encoded png. To write the data, you'll need to do something like the following:

```
function writeScreenshot(data, name) {
  name = name || 'ss.png';
  var screenshotPath = 'C:\\selenium_local_map\\';
  fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath + name, data, 'base64');
};

driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
  writeScreenshot(data, 'out1.png');
});
```

More documentation can be found [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#takeScreenshot)

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Just wanted to add for fellow Node n00bs who are going to copy and paste this then wonder what to do about the resulting error - add the following to line 2: var fs = require('fs');

Comment: For this code to work, you need to include the following line:

var fs      = require('fs');

I spent some time trying to find out what that "fs" was about.
you have to install the package then this solution will work:
_italic_ npm install fs _italic_

Comment: Node.js includes the fs module. You just need to require it, not install it separately.